# Setting exposure compensation with cwac-camera

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm using a SeekBar, and I'd like to set the exposure compensation when the user changes the SeekBar, for the preview surface.

I'm using cwac-camera (CameraView), and I'd like to use Camera.Parameters.setExposureCompensation, however CameraView does not give access to the Camera object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setExposureCompensation()` is a method on `Camera.Parameters`. You are provided a `Camera.Parameters` at various points in time, [such as via `adjustPreviewParameters()`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#arbitrary-preview-configuration).

Comment: Thank you, can you share some code for the onProgressChanged event of the SeekBar that should update the exposure compensation of the CameraView with the value of the SeekBar, and force the CameraView preview to apply it?

Comment: @Jamrelian: I have never used `setExposureCompensation()`, sorry.